# Complex mysql search query with few conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea if that is possible, but i have search for users and i want to bring results on after every typed letter, so I'm trying to make that search work as fast as possible, but my ambitious a too high for my knowledge.

I have `users db`, `relations (id, user_id, follower_id, status)` which one i including using `LEFT JOIN` twice, first as followers and than as following.

So what i would like to do, i to bring result in order, like first i want to get people which user is following and are followed back, than just people which user is following, than people who's following user and finally others. And i want to limit all search to max 10 rows. If that is possible to do somehow only in mysql? i already done that in php, but that involves way to many queries to database.

Also im interesting if there is any way to set know if from what contidion that row is.

**UPDATE**

what i need to get and in what order:

> users under following conditions:
>
> 1. by search query & user following and they following back.
> 2. by search query & user following.
> 3. by search query & people who's following user.
> 4. by search query
>
> Order:
>
> 1. user following and they following back.
> 2. user following.
> 3. people who's following user.
> 4. others.
>
> Limit: 0, 10

I believe there is no way i can simply order result in that particular way, so i think about using subquery or something more complex, but my mysql knowledge is too low, and im not sure if that is possible to do in one query, or i just have to use separate query under each condition.

Comment: your question is incomprehensible, try to explain in a better way what do you want as a result...

Comment: what i want is rows from users tables

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but I would try something like that:

```
select distinct u.* from users u, relations r where u.id = r.user_id or u.id = r.follower_id order by u.id = r.user_id
```

Comment: i have already done that, but in this way i cant order rows i a way i want. I need first get people which user following and they following back, just than if there is not enough rows get people which user is following and if then is not enough people who's following user and finally if there is still limit not reached, find any people from that table who fits in the search query.